# No module named 'gspread' when trying to import gspread

Tags: python, pip, gspread

I am trying to import gspread in Jupyter but this error keeps popping up:
*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread'*

I am using Python version 3.8.1 and pip version 19.3.1. I installed gspread in the command line and it all seems fine but when I try to import it in the notebook I always get an error. Also tried using PyCharm but the same error exists. 
Please, help!

Comment: Check if pip needs a version ie. if you're using the command python3.8 myscript.py you may need to install gspread with pip3.8 install gspread

Comment: Thanks! I installed it again with pip3.8 install gspread but it says requirement already satisfied and the error message still pops up

Comment: Any other ideas why it may not work?

Comment: Try running the code directly from the command line, `python3.8 myscript.py`

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it in Jupyter Notebook using:

```
!pip install gspread==3.6.0
```